# how to create object for a class with only parameterized constructor?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

```
public final class City
{
public final long id;

public final String name;

public final double latitude;

public final double longitude;

public City(long id, String name, double lat, double lng)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = lng;
}

public static City fromJsonObject(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
{
    return new City(json.getLong(WebApi.Params.CITY_ID),
            json.getString(WebApi.Params.CITY_NAME),
            json.getDouble(WebApi.Params.LATITUDE),
            json.getDouble(WebApi.Params.LONGITUDE));
}
}
```

This is my class. I want to access the values of this class in my another class; how do i do that? (value of latitude, longitude, cityid and city name)

Comment: You haven't initialized your final variables. How is your code getting compiled??

Comment: @ShashankKadne Where do you see that the finals are not initialized? Or maybe the OP edited his constructor after your question?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with using the `instance.member` notation: (It's like calling methods, only without the parenthesis ;-)

```
City c = City.fromJsonObject(...);
system.out.println("City name: " + c.name); // etc.
```

Because the members are marked *final* they must be set when declared *or* in the constructor. In this case they are being set in the constructor which is being called from the factory (static) method. However, because they are final, this would be invalid:

```
City c = ...;
c.name = "Paulville"; // oops (won't compile)! can't assign to final member
```

While some might argue to [always] use "getters", since this is an [simple] *immutable object*, I find it (direct member access) a valid approach. However, **one really nice thing about "getters" is that they can be defined in an Interface** as they are really just methods. This handy feature *could* be useful to avoid an ABI-breaking change later, or to enable DI, or allow mocking... but don't over-design :)

(I generally avoid "setters" unless absolutely required... no need to introduce mutable state willy-nilly and, if changing state is required, I like to change it via "actions".)

Happy coding.

---

Now, assuming this question is about *removing* the static factory method while still keeping final members, then it can still be done trivially (however, then this introduces a "constructor that can throw an exception") which is a whole different can of worms... anyway, note that the requirement of assigning to the final members in the constructor is still being fullfilled.

```
// constructors can (ickickly) throw exceptions ...
public City(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
{
    id = json.getLong(WebApi.Params.CITY_ID),
    name = json.getString(WebApi.Params.CITY_NAME),
    latitude = json.getDouble(WebApi.Params.LATITUDE),
    longitude = json.getDouble(WebApi.Params.LONGITUDE));
}
```

Or perhaps it is desired to keep/utilize the factory method while also providing a constructor overload, but this is *really starting to get silly*...

```
public City(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
    : this(City.fromJsonObject(json)) {
    // we do everything in the next constructor, it would be neat if it
    // was possible to do static/local stuff before calling the base constructor
    // (so that we could pass in multiple arguments, but .. not possible in Java)
}

City(City other) {
    // a "copy constructor"
    // just copy over the member values, note no exception from here :)
    // also note that this fulfills the contract of assigning to the final
    // members when used as the base constructor for City(JSONObject)
    id = other.id;
    name = other.name;
    latitude = other.latitude;
    longitude = other.longitude;
}
```

Comment: I am getting java.nullpoint exception when I am accessing the variables from another class..I just want to use the values.Dont want to modify them.

Comment: @Maddy Maybe `null` was the value assigned (to `name`, the other fields can't be null as they are primitive types)? That is, can/does `getString` return null? Or perhaps it's not related to this class at all?